# Why are different mesenchymal stem cells used for articular, auricular, septal nasal and costal chondrocytes?

Tags: cell-biology, stem-cells, cartilage

[image]

Why do stem cell researchers use the mesenchymal stem cells shown in the table above for these specific types of chrondrocytes? Can you only use bone marrow to make articular cartilage, or are there other types of cartilage that can be made using bone marrow, if so which other types of cartilage?

Comment: Who is "they"? Why are certain cells in the body of different lineages than other, somewhat similar cells? Because that's how the body evolved. "Why" questions about evolution are rarely informative or helpful.

Comment: @MattDMo: I was referring to stem cell researchers. For example: Can you only use bone marrow to make articular cartilage, or are there other types of cartilage that can be made using bone marrow, if so which other types of cartilage?

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks for clarifying. You might want to add the ideas of your entire comment to the question so everyone understands.